# Travel insurance in the US when domestic health insurance is provided by the employer

Tags: usa, health-insurance, insurance

My employer in the US provides sufficient health insurance in the US. But my job (and my private live) involves short-term travels to other parts of the world, including my original country (Germany).

What is the right name for the kind of insurance I need there?

(In Germany, I would get a „Auslandsreisekrankenversicherung“, which covers all travels abroad for ~8€ a year.)

Comment: My US employer provides health insurance that covers me anywhere in the world (though in other countries the coverage is on "out of network" terms).  Are you certain that yours does not?

Comment: They told me “The … health insurance only offers international coverage for life-threatening emergencies in which there is immediate danger to your life and/or a limb.”

Answer (score 1):

You need a travel insurance policy covering medical emergencies and possible repatriation. Policies normally also cover trip cancelation, lost baggage, accidents etc. Single trip and multiple trip policies are available. Multiple trip policies are usually cheaper if you make several trips a year.